# Nginx usage - java jetty + angular2 node.js

Tags: java, nginx, angular

I have no idea if it is possible but I heard that the best practice is to create a frontend project and a backend project as two independence projects. To do that, I should use Nginx, right? But how exactly do that and how exactly is it works?

I just create an angular2 project with node.js and start the server to listen to for example 80 port.

Then I create a java project with jetty and start the server to listen to for example 90 port.

Then, should I in some way create Nginx project to merge frontend and backend? I need help cause I'm afraid I can't understant how to do that.

Comment: `nginx` would host your project. Node.js is essentially "Backend" for an HTML/JS frontend - although obviously you can mix and match various languages for front and back end stuff. You don't even _need_ `nginx` if you want to just host using node.js, but I'd still recommend it.

Comment: Node.js *is* a backend... What's Jetty for? The only purpose of Nginx is a "reverse proxy"/load balancer/static resource server

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're mixing up a few things here:

In general it would make sense that your project is either written in `JavaScript`, and is running in `Node.js`, or written in `Java` (or a JVM language) as a Servlet, in which case it will run inside a Servlet Container like `Jetty` or `Tomcat`.

A web server like `nginx` or `Apache httpd` can be placed in front of the backend service in order to handle static content, provide caching, security, load balancing etc.